# Why can not add subversion package to my OpenBSD 4.5 machine?

Tags: svn, openbsd, packages

I have an OpenBSD 4.5 on a virtual machine. I configured the net and my machine can connect to the OpenBSD FTP repository in Canada (ftp.openbsd.org) correctly. But when I execute this line:

> *pkg_add -v subversion-1.5.5*

Occurs this error:

> *Unknown element: @sha FTlY/mreDMe9nRNLR5+fSIIZWMnivjO0p83rQLSL6F0= in SCALAR(0x7deeda80), at /usr/libdata/perl5/OpenBSD/PackingList.pm line 301, line 7.*

Does anybody know why I cannot install this package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this happen when using packages from a different version to the OS.

The kernel, userland and packages must all be from the same version.

Which includes not mixing between `-RELEASE` and `-CURRENT` (CVS HEAD or snapshots).

Comment: Ohhh!!! Your answer is correct. I installed the OpenBSD 4.4 version and I'm trying to install the subversion package for 4.5 version. Sorry, I suppose this is a very newbie user.